snowflake - dynamic tables operation
Currently we have a lot of streams and tasks to capture inserts and updates for dozens of raw tables and when the streams over this raw tables capture changes triggers tasks that call procedures that merge that data into final tables, pretty standard. The thing is that this final tables has dozens of columns but the ON condition in the merge is only made with the "primary compound key" always with a couple of columns like id's, codes and some date.
Now i'm trying to understand if we could do this same thing but with dynamic tables. Per snowflake documentations they show that one could replace:
stream and task solution:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE raw
(var VARIANT);

CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM rawstream1
ON TABLE raw;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE names
(id INT,
first_name STRING,
last_name STRING);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK raw_to_names
WAREHOUSE = mywh
SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
WHEN
SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('rawstream1')
AS
MERGE INTO names n
USING (
SELECT var:id id, var:fname fname,var:lname lname FROM rawstream1
) r1 ON n.id = TO_NUMBER(r1.id)
WHEN MATCHED AND metadata$action = 'DELETE' THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND metadata$action = 'INSERT' THEN UPDATE SET n.first_name = r1.fname, n.last_name = r1.lname
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND metadata$action = 'INSERT' THEN INSERT (id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES (r1.id, r1.fname, r1.lname);

with:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE raw
(var VARIANT);

CREATE OR REPLACE DYNAMIC TABLE names
TARGET_LAG = '1 minute'
WAREHOUSE = mywh
AS
SELECT var:id::int id, var:fname::string first_name,var:lname::string last_name FROM raw;

This seems to show that all the columns, in this case are been used as the ON condition in the merge solution, so if any new rows has any different value of a previous already loaded register is going to be inserted, like seems to this solutions doesn't contemplate updates. Is this the way that dynamic tables works?
Or there's a way to tell the dynamic table that, in the example, var:id::int is the "ON" condition to join the new data with the final table and the other two columns should be updated?
Or this is not possible with dynamic tables and we should continue using streams and tasks?
Edit, example of a final table and data added into table1 (raw data)
final table
id_final  name_final  timestamp_update_final
1         Bob         2024-09-12 01:01:01
2         Jack        2024-09-12 02:01:01

table1 (new data added)
id_raw  name_raw        timestamp_update_raw
1       Bob Jackson     2024-09-13 01:01:01
2       Jack Ryan       2024-09-13 02:01:01
3       Katy Adams      2024-09-13 03:01:01

With standard merge using stream data and defining only id_raw = id_final, the final table would result in this:
final table
id_final  name_final        timestamp_update_final
1         Bob Jackson       2024-09-13 01:01:01
2         Jack Ryan         2024-09-13 02:01:01
3         Katy Adams        2024-09-13 03:01:01

But if i'm not understanding dynamic tables wrong, using the same example of snowflake docs, final table would be:
id_final  name_final        timestamp_update_final
1         Bob               2024-09-12 01:01:01
2         Jack              2024-09-12 02:01:01
1         Bob Jackson       2024-09-13 01:01:01
2         Jack Ryan         2024-09-13 02:01:01
3         Katy Adams        2024-09-13 03:01:01

Or am i wrong?

@LukaszSzozda added above

A Dynamic Table physicalises a query - so whatever the result of the query is at the point the DT is refreshed is what the DT will contain

It seems that a raw table is "append-style" and only the latest version is expected as an output:
CREATE OR REPLACE DYNAMIC TABLE names
TARGET_LAG = '1 minute'
WAREHOUSE = mywh
AS
SELECT *
FROM raw
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_raw 
                          ORDER BY timestamp_update_raw DESC) = 1;

Important: If a raw table is truncated, a dynamic table will be empty. Deleting a row from raw requires removing all its previous versions(alternatively soft deletion mechanism - marking row as deleted).

mm yeah but this would work if for example i received two updates over the same id and would need to update only with the last one, and i need to the dynamic table evaluates a certain ON condition like in a merge and update the other columns, like i state above in the example, the dynamic table as receive 3 different new rows in the raw table, is gonna insert the 3 new rows or update the 2 that already exists (the id exists)? because if thats what it does, doesn't work for our purpose

@RobertinoBonora QUALIFY clause is used to preserve only single/newest version per PARTITION BY column (in your case what you call as "ON condition"). I suggest to test it if it matches your requirements

dude thank u very much, i wasn't understanding really how it work, but yeah with the qualify partitioned by the "pk" the DT returns always the newest version of each row. Thanks!
